# JQuery Date Picker Manual Input

Tags: jquery

I am using Jquery Datepicker, with format 'mm/yyyy', I am allowing manual input on it. I am having two problems in it
1. When I am just clicking on textbox and not select any date, then after I click outside the textbox, the date get selected
2. When user manually adds the date and if he clears the textbox with backspace, then after clicking outside the textbox the date get selected.

I also want to apply validation on manual input, Kindly see this [Fiddle Code](http://jsfiddle.net/JTL3M/6/)
This is my date picker

```
   $("#dtpick").datepicker({
                prevText: "",
                nextText: "",
                changeMonth: true,
                changeYear: true,
                showButtonPanel: true,
                dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
                onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                      if ($(this).val() == "") {
              var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                      }
                }
            });
```

Comment: you are setting the date on datepicker in `onClose` event(when value is empty). If you remove this, your date will not be entered on `onblur` of datepicker. Correct me, if i misunderstood the question.

Comment: If I remove the empty condition, it will add not add the manually entered date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
         $("#dtpick").datepicker({
            prevText: "",
            nextText: "",
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            showButtonPanel: true,
            dateFormat: 'mm/yy',
            onClose: function (dateText, inst) {
                  if ($(this).val() == "undefined") {
                      alert("");
          var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
                var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
                $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
                  }
            }
        });
```